# Finding the correct RegEx pattern for Initials

Tags: regex, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I'm hoping this a problem RegEx can solve but I have not been able to figure out the write pattern.

I'm trying to append a period to the end of capital letters after whitespace or if its at the end of the string.

For example:

```
FullName = "John A A Smith C.P.A." to "John A. A. Smith C.P.A."
```

or

```
Prefix = "Mr." to "Mr." (unchanged)
FirstName = "John A" to "John A."
MiddleName = "A" to "A."
LastName = "Smith" to "Smith" (unchanged)
Suffix = "C.P.A." To "C.P.A" (unchanged)
```

This is the last mutation of the regex pattern I've tried: "\b[A-Z][^.]\b"
This is the replacement pattern: "$&."

The problem is "C.P.A." turns into "C..P..A.."

Is there anyway to avoid this?

Thanks for reading my question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try one of the following expressions

```
([A-Z](?=\s)|[A-Z][^\.]$)
([A-Z](?=\s)|[A-Z][^\.]$|\b[A-Z]\b$)
(\b[A-Z]\b)(?!\.)
```

Replacement

```
$1.
```

Usage in JavaScript

```
'John A A Smith C.P.A'.replace(/([A-Z](?=\s)|[A-Z][^\.]$)/g, "$1.");
'John A A Smith C.P.A.'.replace(/([A-Z](?=\s)|[A-Z][^\.]$)/g, "$1.");
```

Output:

```
John A. A. Smith C.P.A.
John A. A. Smith C.P.A.
```

[Demo 1](http://regex101.com/r/yN6zH1/1) | [Demo 2](http://regex101.com/r/yN6zH1/2) | [Demo 3](http://regex101.com/r/yN6zH1/3)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'll try the pattern you gave, but on the site you linked for the demo looks like it will do the job!

Comment: @Zabalba As you saw, I tested it on all the samples provided. However, if you find a problem, please drop me a message here :)

Comment: This regex does not seem to be matching "A A" to convert to "A. A." Is there any tweak to catch these variations?

Comment: @Zabalba I'll check it in a few minutes.

Comment: I tried this "([A-Z](?=\s)|[A-Z][^\.]$|\b[A-Z]$)" Do you forsee any complication from using boundary?

Comment: @Zabalba Actually, I'm afraid this `\b[A-Z]\b$` is redundant (in this case); 'cause we already caver this case having this `(?=\s)`

Comment: Hmmm. I can see on the regex101.com site your version 3 should work but its not working on the string that I'm testing using Visual Studio 2012. I'm wondering if its a .NET thing. In any case I'm using the full boundary you provided. That works like a charm. Thanks for showing me how to handle these encounters :D

Comment: @Zabalba Just updated the answer adding the last expression from comments; in the meantime I'll do some more tests and let you know about the results.